# How to set response headers with Rikulo Stream server?

Tags: http-headers, dart, rikulo

I have one API that returns information in JSON, and for that, I would indicate that the content-type of the HttpResponse is application/json.
So, with Rikulo, I have something like :

```
connect.response.headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, contentTypes['json']);
```

But when I request my API, it told me that the headers are immutable.

```
HttpException: HTTP headers are not mutable
#0      _HttpHeaders._checkMutable (http_headers.dart:267:21)
#1      _HttpHeaders.set (http_headers.dart:31:18)
```

Therefore, how can I set my response headers, or there is a native solution with Rikulo to return JSON data ?

Comment: Make sure you have not outputted anything before sending out the headers.

Comment: Indeed, I had written things before changing the header. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the contentType property directly:

```
connect.response.headers.contentType = contentTypes["json"];
```

If you'd like to set the header instead, you have to pass a String object (which Dart SDK expects):

```
connect.response.headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,
  contentTypes['json'].toString());
```

But the error message shall not be as you posted. Like Kai suggested in the comment, the message indicates you have output some data before setting the header.

Comment: I was wrong in both these cases. I had written something before setting my header and I didn't used the correct syntaxe to do it. Thank you :)